# php memcache works in the CLI only

Tags: php, browser, memcached, command-line-interface

```
<?php 

$m = new Memcache;
```

in CLI no errors.

In Browser is:

```
[ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Memcache' not found
```

in file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
is line with extension=memcache.so

in file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini is line with extension=memcache.so too

Apache was restarted...

Comment: Do you use some kind of autoloader? Tried $m = new \Memcache; ?

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem was not installed

```
apt-get install php5-memcache
```

after apache restart it works